# Метод makeKeyAndOrderFront Cocoa API не работает

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Написал небольшую программу на Objective-C (Cocoa), которая показывает окно с WebView в котором открывается переданная в командной строке ссылка. Программа строится как Tool и в ней 3 файла исходников. И всё работает как задумано за исключением проблемы - окно открывается не в фокусе, а если передать щелчком ему фокус, то щелчки мыши проходят, а нажатия клавиж и движения колесом попадают в окно, которое было активным до этого (например терминал). Засада где-то с порядком инициализации или типа того. Прошу уважаемую общественность оказать практическую помощь.

**TinyBrowser.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

#import "TinyController.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    TinyController * controller = [[TinyController alloc] init];
    [NSApp setDelegate:controller]; 

    [controller navigate:[NSString stringWithCString:(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "http://ya.ru/")]];

    [NSApp run];

    [controller release];
    [NSApp release];    
    [pool release];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

**TinyController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface TinyController : NSObject {
        NSWindow * window;
    WebView * view;
    }

-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;

-(void)navigate:(NSString *)url_string;

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;

@end
```

**TinyController.m**

```
#import "TinyController.h"

@implementation TinyController

-(id)init {
[super init];

NSRect geometry = NSMakeRect(0,0,1024,768);

view = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:geometry];
[view setFrameLoadDelegate:self];   

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:geometry
    styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask
    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
    defer:NO];
[window setTitle:@"Tiny Browser"];

[window setContentView:view];
[window setInitialFirstResponder:view];
[window setDelegate:self];
[window center];

return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
[window release];
[view release];

[super dealloc];
}

-(void)navigate:(NSString *)url_string {
[[view mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]]];
}

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
[NSApp terminate:self];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
NSLog(@"%@ %@",[error localizedFailureReason],[error localizedDescription]);
}

@end
```